# customize endpoint of web service when generating using axis2?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, endpoint

dears
I have developed a soap webservice using java and axis2
and a top down approach
now when I deploy the service on tomcat8 server
the location tag of the service is being like:

```
"serverIP:port/projectName/services/serviceName"
```

note the
is there a way to change it to

```
"serverIP:port/projectName/subdomain/anothersubdomain"
```

I have tried editing the web.xml and axis2.xml
note the the the originale wsdl have the location tag : "serverIP:port/projectName/servicename"
therefore I have tried to set the "useOriginalwsdl" to false
and set the "modifyUserWSDLPortAddress" to false in service.xml file
that gave the orginal tag location
but the when I am trying to use endpoint from SoapUI program I can not reach it

I have done some searching where I found that u could customize the endpoint url using Binding provider like below:

```
try { 
            EmployeeServiceService service = new EmployeeServiceService();
            EmployeeService port = service.getEmployeeServicePort();

            BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
            bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://server1.grallandco.com:8282/HumanRessources/EmployeeServiceService");

            Employee emp = port.getEmployee(123);



            System.out.println("Result = "+ emp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {...
```

but since I have generated the code using axis2 generating tool I ddnot know where I could tat code snippet
therefore, what is the best way to customize the endpoint when generating web service using axis2 generating tool